# Deleting Dropbox using their directions

Tags: dropbox

I went to the Dropbox Help Center to get their directions on deleting the program. The directions are written in computer code such as:

```
rm - rf /var/lib/dropbox
```

I know this means something to some people - not me. So, I worry that I have no idea what I'm typing into the bar, Should I have concerns about using their directions to delete their program?

Answer (score 1):

No that removes the dropbox in your system. Let me explain the code

```
rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox
```

- `rm`: linux remove command
- `-rf`: options passed to `rm` command where `r` stands for recursive [move into subdirectories], and `f` means remove without asking.
- `/var/lib/dropbox`: this is the location of the dropbox folder to remove.

To run this command do the following:

1. Open terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>, or click `windows` button and type `terminal`
2. Type the commands into the terminal that appears:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dropbox
   ```

   - The `sudo` here elevates your ability and makes it possible for you to delete that folder which only members of the `sudo` group can and these are owned by the `root` user. `sudo` is a program that makes it possibel for you to act like the `root user` without needing to change to `root`.
   - To see what you can do as a member of the `sudo` group run `sudo -l` and you should see something like this:

     > Matching Defaults entries for georgek on georgek-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:
     >   env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin,
     >   log_host, log_year, logfile=/var/log/sudo.log
     >
     > User georgek may run the following commands on georgek-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:
     >   (ALL : ALL) ALL
   - `(ALL : ALL) ALL` means I can execute any command as any user or any group from any host

     ```
     format: user (host)=(user:group) commands.
     ```

Comment: George, I need you to explain to me what "sudo" means and I  am not clear what your last sentence means at all: "To earn more type ...." Please clarify. Other than that, I am thinking that with your explanation I feel much more at ease.. Hmm except your saying "No. that removes the dropbox ib .." What is "ib"? Feel free to assume I am at the kindegarten at best level re all this.

Comment: @suzannewilliams `sudo` makes it possible for you to remove files and folders that are owned by the `root user` no ordinary user can do that you have to be in the `sudo` group. And for `earn` I meant `learn`

Comment: Thank you so much George! Esp since Dropbox keeps trying to sneak back into my active programs/installations. Grrrrr. I'll go back to where I wrote down their directions and, if I understand correctly, whenever I need to type in a new command, use sudo first. Correct?

Comment: Only if that command requires administrative privileges, sudo isn't needed in all cases... PLEASE BE CAUTIOUS!!!

Comment: Sounds like, since I'm a total novice to ridding myself of non-Google apps, I'd do better following their directions as is.